# (Laravel) How to add errors in custom validators?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I followed this short tutorial: http://blog.elenakolevska.com/laravel-alpha-validator-that-allows-spaces/.

Now my question is, how can i add errors to it? Because now i just get this as an error:

```
validation.alpha_spaces
```

I'm also curious on how to add numbers to the validator?
Thanks!

Edit:

If you don't want to open the link, this is basicly my code:

```
Validator::extend('alpha_spaces', function($attribute, $value) {
    return preg_match('/^[\pL\s]+$/u', $value);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a custom error message as well, for example:

```
Validator::extend('alpha_spaces', function($attribute, $value) {
    // ...
});
```

Now prepare a message for this custom rule:

```
$messages = array('alpha_spaces' => 'Your custom error message for :attribute');
```

Use it like this (with `$messages`):

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Here `:attribute` will be replace with the form's field name.

Comment: Thanks this works. I have placed the $messages array in the controller. Is this right? ^^

Comment: No problem, it's fine :-)